# Boilerplate JSFiddle in tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, jsfiddle

Note that this only really pertains to javascript plugin type tags. Like [fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fullcalendar) or [momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/momentjs).

### Background

When answering or asking a question that warrants a fiddle, I usually pull up one that contains boilerplate or is related to the topic as a starting point. For example, I might use [fullcalendar fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/abryb4sj/).

It's not a lot of code, but it still takes some time to make. Especially since you have to manually add 3 CDN external scripts. Saving yourself a couple of minutes every question adds up fast.

And so I had an idea for tag wikis and I'm wondering if people think it would be useful.

### Boilerplate fiddles in tag wikis

Would it be useful to have an example fiddle as a possible starting point in tag wikis?

**Pros:**

- Eliminates some trivial questions like "x doesn't display anything"
- Increases chance of a fiddle from users who may not understand how to add CDN resources.
- Generally convenient for people to use as a starting point.
- Could be commented to act as a very basic tutorial.

**Cons:**

- If a tag wiki isn't updated, the script will not stay at the latest version.
- May not be used at all (do new users look at tag wikis very often?)
- JSFiddle is 3rd party: availability issues, etc.
- May indicate that fiddles are a requirement. They clearly are not, though I imagine a lot of very poor quality questions would not even be asked if they made fiddles first...

So, is this/should this be:

- Encouraged
- Optional
- Discouraged as not useful or problematic
- Not allowed

Comment: @deduplicator i don't think you can use stack snippets in wikis, can you?

Comment: That should be stack-snippets. Though they really don't work in tag-wikis, you are right. Anyway, it might be better to only link them in the tag-wiki anyway. As you would be fored to do with jsfiddle also.